# Beetween & Join в одно запросе

Tags: c#, linq

```
var DaySet = db.DateSet.Where(p => p.Date >= start && p.Date <= end); //Достаем сет данных из БД 

var DaySet = db.DateSet.Join(db.DrinkSet,
                    p => p.Drink_id,
                    c => c.Name,
                    (p, c) => new
                    {
                      p.Id,
                      c.Name,
                      p.Date,
                      p.Quantity

                    });
```

Как сделать из этого один запрос ?

```
var DaySet = db.DateSet.Where(p => p.Date >= start && p.Date <= end).Join(db.DrinkSet,
                                                                                                    p => p.Drink_id,
                                                                                                    c => c.Name,
                                                                                                    (p, c) => new
                                                                                                    {
                                                                                                        id = p.Id,
                                                                                                        drink_Id = c.Name,
                                                                                                        date = p.Date,
                                                                                                        quantity = p.Quantity

                                                                                                    });
```

ругается на Join - попытайтесь явно определить аргументы типа

Вот мой контекст данных

```
class DatesContext : DbContext
    {
        public DatesContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Day> DateSet { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Drink> DrinkSet { get; set; }

    }

    class Day 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Drink_id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
      public class Drink 
    { 
        public int Id{ get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Где я в Join допустил ошибку?

Comment: `var DaySet = db.DateSet.Where(...).Join(...);` ?

Comment: `p => p.Drink_id, c=>Id, ... ` ?

Comment: а вообще, если у вас связь между таблицами, вы можете её выразить в своих классах, см [Отношение один ко многим](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/3.5.php)